# center text with letter-spacing on hover only css

Tags: html, css, text, behavior

i try something when i hover my button. Currenttly that's my code

```css
.btn {
  border:solid 1px purple;
  color:purple;
  background: white;
  padding:10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s;
}

.btn:hover{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">My bouton</button>
```

The problem is, when i hover my button, the text expand, the button expand too on the right. 
I want to make button not expand (keep original size), only text inside expand and centerized, without put a width size, because i want it as component (I would never know the size of the text.)
ALL in css only.

The only one way i've find is to add a data attribute who come over, but i don't like this way because i reapt my text 2 times.

For you it's possible only CSS ? if yes how ? Thanks a lot

Comment: A way you can go about doing this is to use jQuery / javascript. Are you open to that idea? Cause you need to calculate the width per dynamic content, thus, javascript / jQuery will be much easier with minimal code.

Comment: Precisely, with javascript I can do it, I would like, if it is possible, do it in css only

Comment: Don't think its possible with css when you have to calculate current width. If you want the answer in jquery, I can post it. I've tested it and it works in Jquery. But since its CSS only, I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the original button text and use it inside the after/before using below CSS rules.

```css
.btn {
  border: solid 1px purple;
  color: white;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:hover::after{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.btn::after{
  content: 'My Button';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: purple;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">My bouton</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, as I said in my description, I used this method, using the data attribute, it makes me repeat my text 2 times (DRY)

Comment: Yes, I think this is not possible with pure CSS. By using scale we can achieve an effect close to the above one.  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/alishapatel/5j7fyzuq/1/)

Comment: Thanks, i have thinking to use this way but , it's not exactly that designer want

Answer (score 0):

Most easy solution would be to give the button a width... but you don't want that.

As an alternative, you can play with the `padding-left` and `padding-right`.

In normal state, you give it some more padding, on hover state, bring it back to 15px.

Note: changing the text length will affect the width, the padding then needs to be adjusted too...

```css
.btn {
  border:solid 1px purple;
  color:purple;
  background: white;
  padding:10px 20px 10px 19px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s;
}

.btn:hover{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">My bouton</button>
```

Comment: when increasing the text button width also increases.

Comment: This doesn't work, when there is a longer dynamic text, the issue still exists. Try changing the text inside to *My bouton Lorem Pixel* and you can see it.

Comment: @Gosi, that's why I added the **note**

Comment: @LinkinTED So, when the content comes in dynamically, how does the padding change? You'll have to manually change the padding?

Comment: Yes, in this workaround solution, you'll need to do that. Surely it isn't ideal, but I didn't find a better one

Comment: @LinkinTED Then there is no different then adding *width*. The reason why he didn't want to use *width* is because he doesn't want to manually add it as the contents are dynamic.

Comment: @Gosi, I'm thrilled to see your solution. When I come up with a better one, I'll surely share it.

Comment: how is this centerized?

Comment: @robotik, good comment, changed the answer

Comment: this will not work for any text

Answer (score 0):

use absolute positioning on the text element and set it relative to the button element

**edit:**

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px purple;
  color: purple;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s;
  width: 5em;
}

.btn:hover {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

span {
  //position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
     <span>My button</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Please add an example of that.

Comment: try the above it works but width is fixed. You can go further add a div layer and make it responsive

Comment: Did you try your code? I've put it in a snippet :)

Comment: Thanks, i've try it before you show me it, probleme is, you fix a with, and i want it as component, i'll never now size of the text.

Answer (score -4):

As long as the button width is determined by the text width you can only try to manipulate the padding so it fits again.

If its no problem to give the button a width depending on its parent or a fixed width you can try this:

```css
.btn {
  border:solid 1px purple;
  color:purple;
  background: white;
  padding:10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s;
  width: 95px;
}

.btn:hover{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">My bouton</button>
```

Comment: The OP requested a solution without a fixed width...